# How do you toggle a button with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**Note:** Using Vue.js and Vuetify.js for functionality and styling.

With `:class` and `@click` properties, I was able to change the button's background color to desired color, but it applies the change to **all of them**, and not just the one that I clicked on.

**Question: How do I have a button toggled without having all of them toggled at once?**

In my vue file:

```
<v-layout>
  <v-flex md6>
    <v-text-field>Welcome.</v-text-field>
  </v-flex md6>
  <v-flex id="icon-filter">
    <span>Filter by:</span>
    <v-btn class="filter-button" :class="{toggled: isToggled}" @click="isToggled = !isToggled"><v-icon>local_offer</v-icon></v-btn>
    <v-btn class="filter-button" :class="{toggled: isToggled}" @click="isToggled = !isToggled"><v-icon>notifications</v-icon></v-btn>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

In the `script` section of same vue file:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        companies,
        msg: "indiv",
        dashboards: ['profile', 'charts'],
        isToggled: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've read through this question, but I get a Vue warning, mentioning that I have `isToggled` method as already defined data property. [Toggle Class for an item Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094217/toggle-class-for-an-item-vue-js)

I also read through vue.js docs on data binding, but still need help on this.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Vuetify framework has toggled buttons components, but client wants a distinct style, so cannot use this.
https://vuetifyjs.com/components/buttons

Comment: You'll need a separate `isToggled` for each button, like `localOfferIsToggled`.

Comment: Each button should be a separate component, so that they have internal references to their own state. What you're doing right now is updating a global state that is **shared** across all button instances.

Comment: @Terry Can you elaborate more on your comment?

Comment: @Pusheenicorn This question's accepted answer is an example of what Terry is describing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791340/multiple-modal-components-with-vue/46791687#46791687

Comment: Take a look to this article https://webomnizz.com/create-toggle-switch-button-with-vue-js/ which helps to create own custom button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make another vue file (lets call it **button.vue**)...

**button.vue**

```
// template
<v-btn class="filter-button" :class="{toggled: isToggled}" @click="isToggled = !isToggled">
  <slot></slot>
</v-btn>

// script
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      isToggled: false
    }
  }
}
```

**your_parent.vue**

```
// script
import CustomButton from './button.vue'

export default {
  components: { CustomButton },
  data...
}

// template
<v-layout>
  <v-flex md6>
    <v-text-field>Welcome.</v-text-field>
  </v-flex md6>
  <v-flex id="icon-filter">
    <span>Filter by:</span>
    <custom-button><v-icon>local_offer</v-icon></custom-button>
    <custom-button><v-icon>notifications</v-icon></custom-button>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

**Note:** `CustomButton` and `button.vue` can be renamed to whatever is convenient for you

This would allow each `custom-button` to have its own data that can now be toggled!

Answer (score 3):

I would use `@click`  with a function and pass the `$event` to it, then use javascripts `classList.toggle` function to apply a css class or use `.toggle()`do whatever else you want.;

```
@click="myToggleFunction($event)"
```

Then

```
methods: {
   myToggleFunction: function(event){
        let button = event.target;
        button.classList.toggle('toggled');
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly pass the `$event` object in the inline `@click` handler, it gets passed implicitly. Also, `toggleClass` is a jQuery function. In plain JS you'd need to use `button.classList.toggle('toggled')`

Comment: Yes your are right!  It should have been `classList.toggle()`