# Only one button active at a time depending on state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, state

I am writing an app in Vue.js and cannot find a solution to my problem.

Here's my [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mclean-2vfmg)

I have an array of objects, that I transform into an object with false values for each key.

```
sizesArray: [
    { number: "30", id: 1 },
    { number: "36", id: 2 },
    { number: "40", id: 3 }
],
sizesObject: {
    "30": false,
    "36": false,
    "40": false
},
```

I can target each value individually, but how can I toggle the buttons so that only **one value is true at a time**, instead of being toggled individually as I have now?

It seems that For-in loop or a watcher would be great for that, I'm just not sure how to approach it.

I've been sitting on this problem for a couple of hours, and cannot seem to find something similar on stack overflow. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a 'one to many' relationship. Wouldn't it be better to define a variable containing the active value?
`let activeButton = "36"`

Comment: I think it was solved here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814304/how-do-you-toggle-a-button-with-vue-js

Comment: @OrBen-Yossef I can already toggle a single button, my question is now to have only 1 active button at a time out of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably a better approach than the loop method is to just store a reference to the currently active item and reset it on new selection. See [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-violet-sqyo7).

```
toggle: function(number) {
  if (this.activeIndex !== null && this.activeIndex !== number)
    this.sizesObject[this.activeIndex] = false;
  this.sizesObject[number] = !this.sizesObject[number];
  this.activeIndex = number;
}
```

And call it:

```
<button
      v-for="size in this.sizesArray"
      @click="toggle(size.number)"
      :class="{active: sizesObject[size.number]}"
      :key="size.key"
    >{{size.number}}</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop through all entries on any click and set them to `false`. After that you could set the correct one to true. That's just a pretty rudimentary solution and could be improved. However, it visualizes the way to go.

```
  for (const o in this.sizesObject) {
    this.sizesObject[o] = false;
  }

  this.sizesObject[sizeNumber] = true;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bird-chk35

Comment: Amazingly simple and straight forward, I love it! I

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sizesObject in order to implement that logic.
Instead, you can add a data "selected" which stores the selected/clicked button's "id".
And you can choose the active class by checking whether the "selected" value is equal to "id" or not.

This is the full code,

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button
      v-for="size in this.sizesArray"
      @click="setSelected(size.id)"
      :class="{active: selected === size.id}"
      :key="size.key"
    >{{size.number}}</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    {{sizesObject}}
    {{selected}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      sizesArray: [
        { number: "30", id: 1 },
        { number: "36", id: 2 },
        { number: "40", id: 3 }
      ],
      selected: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelected: function(value) {
      this.selected = value;
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.active {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```